# remove substring until end of the line

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string `a`

```
a="to be removed blah blah \r\nrow 2 blah blah\r\nrow 3 more blah blah \r\nto be removed more blah blah \r\nrow 5 final blah blah"
```

I want to do essentially the following
`a=a.replace_all("to be removed...\r\n" ,"")`

so that the output looks like this:

`"row 2 blah blah\r\nrow 3 more blah blah\r\nrow5 final blah blah"`

however, I only know how the lines starts, not the rest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `re.sub` and put a wildcard `.` with repetition `*` that does not greedily include `?` the `\r\n`:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "to be removed blah blah \r\nrow 2 blah blah\r\nrow 3 more blah blah \r\nto be removed more blah blah \r\nrow 5 final blah blah"
>>> a = re.sub(r'to be removed.*?\r\n', '', a)
>>> a
'row 2 blah blah\r\nrow 3 more blah blah \r\nrow 5 final blah blah'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach without using a regular expression:

```
>>> a = "\r\n".join([i for i in a.splitlines() if not 'to be removed' in i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another try may be combination of `search` and `sub` function of `re` module-

```
>>>  a = "to be removed blah blah \r\nrow 2 blah blah\r\nrow 3 more blah blah \r\nto be removed more blah blah \r\nrow 5 final blah blah"
>>>  r = re.sub(re.search(r'to be removed blah blah[\s]+', a,re.I).group(), '', a)
>>>  print r
```